# How to dispplay Selection Field on Tree view ODOO 11

Tags: selection, odoo

Im newbie odoo. I learn odoo from basic. I have a question althought i search on stackoverflow when help odoo but not work .

I have a Selection field of model inherited from res.partner.

I want display value of gender in tree view. How i can do this ?  Please help me

````
```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model='ir.ui.view' id="dyno_lead_view_inherit">
            <field name="name">res.partner.tree.view.inherited</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_tree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="display_name" position="after">
                    <field name="gender"/>
                    <field name="social_id"/>
                    <field name="birthday"/>
                </field>
                <field name="phone" position="after">
                    <field name="customer_job"/>
                    <field name="customer_monthly_income"/>
                    <field name="debt"/>
                    <field name="loan_range"/>
                    <field name="cic_code"/>
                    <field name="address"/>
                    <field name="city"/>
                    <field name="country_id"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
GENDER = ((1, 'Nam'),
          (2, 'Nữ'),
          (3, 'Không xác định'))
gender = Selection(GENDER, string="Giới tính", help='Giới tính')
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to place GENDER in the xml file like this. Instead, in your python model, you should write like this:

```
class YourClass(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    gender = fields.Selection([('1', 'Nam'),('2', 'Nữ'),('3', 'Không xác định')])
```

Hope it helped, :)

Comment: I write gender in model , not in the xml file :D. All of fields use selection not display. Im read document odoo but document not good

Comment: just add the `fields` before the `Selection` the it will work :)

Comment: from odoo.fields import Selection, Integer, Many2one, Char, Float
Selection import from fields already :D. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

See OCA's partner_contact_gender module at https://github.com/OCA/partner-contact/tree/12.0/partner_contact_gender

This is res.partner.py:

```
# Copyright 2014-2015 Grupo ESOC <www.grupoesoc.es>
# Copyright 2017-Apertoso N.V. (<http://www.apertoso.be>)
# License AGPL-3.0 or later (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html).

from odoo import fields, models


class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    gender = fields.Selection([
        ('male', 'Male'),
        ('female', 'Female'),
        ('other', 'Other')
    ])
```

and this is res_partner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_personal_information_gender" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Partner gender: personal info</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="partner_contact_personal_information_page.personal_information"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='personal_information_page']//group[@name='personal_information_group']">
                <field name='gender'/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: the question is to display in tree view and your answer looks like inheriting a form view.

Comment: You're right, but the same ideas work with list views too, just inherit the right view.